# How to automate significance tests with multiple groups in the dataset between treatment and control

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, anova

I am really new to R.

My data looks like this: Every city belongs to a state and has treatment and control values for the variable Num1. I need to perform a two way t tests or Anova (regardless) to check significance between Num1 values of cities for treatment group and Num1 values for the state for control to which the city belongs (this should be done for each city). The result should be p values for each city treatment- state control group.

```
City Measure_group   State  Day        Num1
A    Treatment        X    01.01.1900   279
A    Control          X    02.01.1900   256
B    Treatment        Y    03.01.1900   71
B    Control          Y    04.01.1900   372
C    Treatment        Z    05.01.1900   127
C    Control          Z    06.01.1900   303
D    Treatment        W    07.01.1900   248
```

I have already tried basic ANOVA to do this but it does not work as it compares all cities to each other without any relationship.

```
    model <- aov( Num1 ~City+State, data= data1)
    comparison <- pairs(lsmeans(model, ~City|State))
    test(comparison, by = NULL, adjust = "fdr")
```